# ServiceWorker losts parent's referrer on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker, referrer

I've noticed a strange behaviour on **Firefox** that iframe pages loaded via ServiceWorker lost parent's referrer.

I have a page embedded via iframe into parent site. The page uses `parent.postMessage()` to communicate with the parent window and takes `document.referrer` as a `targetOrigin` parameter. It also registers a ServiceWorker to use a cached version of a content. When the iframe page is loaded for the first time and ServiceWorker is not registered yet the `document.referrer` has a value of the URL of parent's page as expected. But when I refresh the site and iframe loads a cached version of the page returned by ServiceWorker the `document.referrer` is empty. Are there additional steps that must be done in order to maintain parent's referrer in this cases (like policy headers)? Curiously this does not happen on a webkit-based browers.

ServiceWorker code:

```js
const cacheName = 'XXX';
const resources = [...];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName)
            .then(cache => cache.addAll(resources))
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                  return response;
                }
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
    );
});
```

Thanx,